# Re-render express server view

Tags: node.js, express

I'm developing a command line tool to render a PDF locally based on a Twig template.

My problem is that Express renders the templates once and no matter if I refresh the template code it doesn't get re-rendered.

I have an option to debug the template code by launching a web server and serving contents via:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(template + '/cv.twig', cvData);
});
```

Now, I'm aware of the fs.watch method:

```
fs.watch('views/'+template, function (event, filename) { ... }
```

but I can't force Express to either drop the cache or re-render the template.

I'd like to avoid command line tools like Nodemon or Forever, since it's already a command line tool.

Comment: How do you intend to put this application in production without Forever/PM2?

Comment: There is no production phase. You generate a PDF and you are happy with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Gulp Watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) with [Gulp Twig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-twig). It offers you a possibility to stream file through pipes without restart, an example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('stream', function () {
    // Endless stream mode 
    return watch('css/**/*.css', { ignoreInitial: false })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Comment: The problem is not with watching the file, but rather express serving the same content if I don't restart the server. I'll probably throw express out :)

Comment: With gulp-data+gulp-watch you could pass data direct into pipe (gulp-twig), in this case application become more real time. Also, you are right, you won't be able in express to reload twig page (with modified structure) without pm2/forever/nodemon.